# Can you pass an iterable to an Nuint test like pytest?

Tags: nunit

With Pytest you can pass an iterable to one test method and it will run multiple tests:

```
the_data = [1,2,3,4,5,a,6,7,8]

@pytest.mark.parameterize('arg', the_data)
def test_data(arg):
    assert arg.isnumeric()
```

Can you do that with Nunit (using c#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would use a `[TestCaseSource]` like the following;

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(TheData))]
public void TestData(object i)
{
    Assert.That(i is int);
}

public static IEnumerable TheData => new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'a', 6, 7, 8 };
```

Note that the test data must be static. The above results in the following tests in Visual Studio using the NUnit test adapter.

[image]

Comment: It is not running my [SetUp] between iterations.